# Getting the filters values from CNN layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, autoencoder

I have the following model (for example)

```
input_img = Input(shape=(224,224,1)) # size of the input image
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
```

I have several layers of such in my autoencoder model. I am particularly interested in the filters of the first layer. There are 64 filters each of size 3x3.

To get the filters, I tried using the following code:

```
x.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
```

but I am getting the error as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-96506292d6d7> in <module>()
      4 x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
      5 
----> 6 x.layers[0].get_weights()[0]

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

I am not using the sequential model. My model will be formed using the following command after several such layers.

```
 model = Model()
```

I am new to CNN and I don't even know if the get_weights function can help me get filters value. How do I get value of filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your code is calling the `layers` function on a layer definition itself.

The model first needs to be compiled and then you can use the `layers` function on the model to retrieve the weights of the specific layer.

In your case:

```
weights = model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

will give you the set of weights of the 1st convolutional layer

Which you can use after compiling the model:

```
model = Model(inputs=input_img, output=b)
```

Where `b` refers to the last layer in your model.

Comment: The convolutional layer can be accessed through the index [1] in the call to get_weights, since the first element will now be your input layer

Comment: It gives me an error IndexError: list index out of range. Also, I want to get the filters on the first layer to apply geometric translations on those filters. I don't think this is possible after I compile it. What do you think about it?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, calling the function on the input layer will give you that error, since the input layer does not have weights.

Comment: Not sure I understand the second part of your comment. Are you attempting to create a layer in the model that is a 'geometric translation' (you will have to clarify on this) of the first convolutional layer? You do realise the model is initially compiled with random weights, and first needs to be trained? Because I see no reason to apply transformations to filters containing random weights

Comment: I did it after I compiled my model the same way you showed in the answer but still got the error.

Comment: Please post the full code you are running now as an edit and I will try to help.

Comment: It is not possible to train the layers before compiling the model, so the convolutional layers you want to apply transformations to will just contain random weights. I hope I understand now what you're trying to do. Try this: 1. Compile and train the model with only the input and 1st convolutional layer. 2. After training, apply your transformations on the weights (which are now trained) and compile another model with the transformed layers. Hope that is what you want

Comment: I am able to run it now. I was doing model.layers[0].get_weights() instead of model.layers[1].get_weights(). Thanks.

Comment: Great. Yes I made the edit in the original answer. Now use that method to transform the layers after you have trained the first layer as a standalone model

Comment: I will follow the instructions given by you to apply transformations and let you know if it works